# jQuery remove() not working

Tags: jquery

I have a basic table with a button in each row that allows the user to remove the row in which the button resides. I have an ajax call that has the following success event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: 
        {
            id : $(this).attr('id'),
            action : "removeEntry"
        }, 

        success:function(data)
        {
            alert("Here!");
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }

    }); 
});
```

The 'Here' gets returned correctly, but the remove() statement doesn't seem to be working. I have tried doing $(this).remove() and that does not work either... Any thoughts? Here is what the table structure looks like:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id = "myTable">
    <tr>
    <th>Event Name</th>
    <th>Subdomain</th> 
    <th>Shortcode</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>This is a sample entry</td>
    <td>some data</td>
    <td>some more data</td>
    <td><a href='#'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' id = 'generated_01'></span>
    </a></td>

    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not what you think it is inside the `success` callback

There are various ways to bind a new context. Probably the  most common approach is store a reference to element outside of ajax.

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function () {
     var $element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: 
        {
            id : $(this).attr('id'),
            action : "removeEntry"
        }, 

        success:function(data)
        {
            alert("Here!");
            $element.closest("tr").remove();
        }

    }); 
});
```

You can also use javascript `bind()` and there is also a `context` option of `$.ajax`

Answer (score 2):

Inside the ajax `success` function, `this` is the ajax call (XHR object), not the element.

You can either use a variable

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function () {

    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {id : $(this).attr('id'), action : "removeEntry"}, 
        success:function(data) {
            alert("Here!");
            $(self).closest("tr").remove();
        }
    }); 
});
```

or use context

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        context : this,
        data: {id : $(this).attr('id'), action : "removeEntry"}, 
        success:function(data) {
            alert("Here!");
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }
    }); 
});
```